# Is This A Dynamic Table? Or what

Tags: mysql, optimization

I came across this line of code in a Mysql Script Im trying to optimize(The script takes over 7 hours to run). I discovered that this line is responsible for over 60% of the exec time.

```
# #Fill temp table
SELECT

    DISTINCT clv_temp(view01.user_email,,user_number) AS `Authentic`

FROM(

SELECT DISTINCT u_mail, u_phone

FROM
Cust_orders
ORDER BY order_date ASC

)view01;
```

Comment: what is `clv_temp()` ?

Comment: The order by class in the subselect is pointless, I think.

Comment: clv_temp is supposed to be a temporary table

Comment: Unless you use `EXPLAIN`, you're not going to get far.

Comment: @ Luidi- yes it pointless cos it results in a filesort

Comment: ive used explain.... the main problem is can someone tell me what the select distinct clv_temp(***) as 'Authentic' portion of the query will do... I have rewritten the subquery to prefetch data into a table in the db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The excessive runtime is presumably in the definition of the custom function `clv_temp`, so you will need to find the definition of that.

Note that currently this function is being run for every row returned by the sub-query - i.e. for every unique combination of `u_mail` and `u_phone` in the `cust_orders` table. This is generally a very inefficient way of processing data, and what you will probably need to do is implement the logic currently performed by `clv_temp` in a set-wise manner, rather than one row at a time.